# $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ lipschitz continuous $\Leftrightarrow$ $\exists \ g:\|g\|_\infty<+\infty$ so that $f(x)=\int_{[a,x]}g \ d \lambda$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lipschitz-functions

I want to show:

> $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ lipschitz continuous $\Leftrightarrow$ $\exists \ g:\|g\|_\infty<+\infty$ so that $f(x)=\int_{[a,x]}g \ d \lambda$

Anyone got any hints how to prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not so easy - you have to use *the fundamental theorem of Lebesgue integral calculus* as follows. Since $f$ is Lipschitz-continuoous, it is also absolute continuous. This implies by the fundamental theorem of Lebesgue integral calculus that $f$ is almost everywhere differentiable with derivative $f'$ and
$$f(x) = f(a) + \int_a^x f'(y) \, dy.$$
If $L$ is the Lipschitz-constant, then of course $|f'| \le L$.

The "$\Leftarrow$"-direction is "easy": We have
$$|f(x)-f(y)|  = \Big| \int_x^y g \, d \lambda \Big| \le \|g\|_\infty |x-y|. $$

Comment: That was my idea as well, but I was unsure because in the statement there is no $f(a)$ on the right side of the equation. For the '<=' direction our script says that if $g$ is $\lambda$ integrable then $f(x):=\int_{[a,x]}g d \lambda$ is absolutely continuous. How do I show that $f$ is lipschitz? Does it have something to do with $[a,x]$ being compact?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got the other direction. But is the $f(a)$ in $f(x)=f(a)+\int_{a}^{x}f'(y) dy$ missing in the statement I should prove?

Comment: @user610431 The statement is correct as it is iff $f(a)=0$. It becomes correct in general if you add $f(a)$ to the right side.